# Session Preview - Authorization failed

Tags: experience-manager

I am configuring UI 2012 on Tridion 2011 SP1 HR2

I am currently bamboozled by an error I get when clicking "Update Preview"

It makes a call to

> /WebUI/Models/SiteEdit/Services/Services.svc/GetPreviewToken

and returns

> {"ExceptionDetail":null,"ExceptionType":null,"Message":"Authorization
>   failed. Please make sure the proper username and password have been
>   configured in the Publication Target.","StackTrace":null}

I have commented out all security sections in `cd_ambient_conf` files

Comment: Nice use of the word bamboozled

Comment: Your OData webservice is probably still configured to use security (that's the default). Change it, look here for a sample: http://code.google.com/p/kickstart-tridion-environment/source/browse/#svn%2FCreateAnEnvironmentForMe%2FCreateAnEnvironmentForMe%2FConfigSamples%2Fpreview-webservice

Comment: Could you verify that the oData webservice is indeed called by checking the IIS logs? And that is returns a 401 when being called from the content manager?

Answer (score 4):

On the publication target properties in the CMS you most likely need to specify the authorization credentials. See screenshot.

[image]